# Is there any way to have a single static field value for all C<>?

Tags: c#, generics

I'd like to write a class C such that it has a static field which is initialized once and remains constant for all C<>.

Is this possible?

Here's the example I'm working with:

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine (C<A>.Value);
    Console.WriteLine (C<B>.Value);
    Console.WriteLine (C<A>.Value2);
    Console.WriteLine (C<B>.Value2);
}

class C<T>
{
    static O O = new O();
    public static string Value { get { return "value of C<T> where T : " + typeof(T).Name; } }
    public static string Value2 { get { return O.ToString() ?? "value of C<T> where T : " + typeof(T).Name; } }
}

class O
{
    Guid guid;
    public O()
    {
        this.guid = Guid.NewGuid();
        Console.WriteLine ("O created {0}", this.guid);
    }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.guid.ToString();
    }
}

class A
{
}

class B
{
}
```

**Output:**

```
value of C<T> where T : A
value of C<T> where T : B
O created 05e6885b-2aa3-4d0d-aec1-fefbe5294f07
05e6885b-2aa3-4d0d-aec1-fefbe5294f07
O created 864554bf-6980-4a0f-9b63-4c0affa21222
864554bf-6980-4a0f-9b63-4c0affa21222
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, derive C from BaseC and declare the static field there, like this:

```
class BaseC
{
    protected static O = new O();
}

class C<T>: BaseC ...
```

Comment: OK! that was pathetically easy but very helpful.

Comment: The only problem would be if he wanted the class `C<T>` to be a static class. Then he could not derive from the non-generic base class. But he would still want put the static field in another class. He **could** write a property in the class `C<T>` that gets and sets the field in the other class, then.